# White space right from page on small screens only (Safari on desktop and Chrome on mobile phone)

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

There is a white space on the right side of every page on my website. This white space only appears when the screen width is smaller than 767 pixels so it must be one of the media queries causing it but I can't find the cause. I tried changing widths and overflows on the `body` element aswell as the `#top` element, `.header` element and `#menu` element. I suspect one of those to cause the problem but I'm puzzled. Strangely this only happens on Safari on my desktop, but on my mobile phone it also happens on Chrome.

See [this website](http://www.theplanter.nl/) on a smaller screen width.

Does anyone have any useful insights?

Comment: In which browser?

Comment: Using Safari only, but also on Chrome on my mobile phone. The other browsers actually don't show this white space (forgot to mention, I'm editing my post now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Please check the image u are using a "row" there remove that. That was there is a horizontal scroll showing

Comment: I'm using a platform that has themes so I did not know this. Thanks for noticing! I'm changing it right away.

Comment: This is the absolute cause of the white space, rather than using html{overflow:hidden); I have changed this and it solved the issue for good.

Answer (score 4):

Please add Css

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   html {overflow-x: hidden;}
 }
```

Comment: This did the trick on both desktop and mobile, thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

> IT because you didn't follow bootstrap framework...When ever you use
>   `row` you must use `col` after that like `<div class="row"></div
>   class="col-sm-12">`

In above case you use `row` in `header` but after that you didnt use `col` add `col` div after row OR use

```
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```